# Angular 7 Subscribe fill model array

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 7 and I would like fill my array model with subscribe return.

When I do:

```
  rsvp: RSVP[];

  constructor(private rsvpService: EventoRsvpService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.rsvpService.obterListaRSVP().subscribe(
       rsvp => {
         this.rsvp = rsvp
         console.log(this.rsvp)
       }
     )
  }
```

I have on the console:

[image]

And when I use this on *ngFor , **total_confirmados** can be used with {{rsvp.total_confirmados}} for example. But I don't have **total_confirmados** in my RSVP model. Look:

```
export class RSVP{
    nome: string
    email: string
    totalConfirmados: number
}
```

Is it correct? Or should I work in my subscribe return to fill their values on the appropriate fields? I prefer to use **totalConfirmados** (of RSVP model) and not  **total_confirmados** (JSON return).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to transform to appropriate format.

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.rsvpService.obterListaRSVP().subscribe(
   rsvp => {
     this.rsvp = rsvp.map(r => ({
        nome: r.nome, 
        email: r.email,
        totalConfirmados: r.total_confirmados      
      }));
     console.log(this.rsvp)
   }
 )
}
```

but refactoring your code to better format (not subscribing)  would be like this :

```
rsvp$: Observable<RSVP[]>;

constructor(private rsvpService: EventoRsvpService) { }

ngOnInit() {
 this.rsvp$ = this.rsvpService.obterListaRSVP().pipe(
   map( rsvp => rsvp.map(r => ({
        nome: r.nome, 
        email: r.email,
        totalConfirmados: r.total_confirmados      
      }))
   ),       
 )
}
```

^ Above code , first map is of RxJs, second map is of array .

In the html

```
*ngFor="let rsvp of rsvp$|async"
```